Why does SQL Server require a LEFT JOIN to retrieve a status that doesn't exist?
I was recently querying our internal database inventory tool for a list of servers, instances and databases, and was adding the corresponding status to each server, instance and database.
Relationship Diagram
Server ˂-- 1 : n --˃ Instance ˂-- 1 : n --˃ Database
   ˄                    ˄                      ˄
   |                    |                      |
   |                  1 : 1                    |
   |                    |                      |
   |                    ˅                      |
   +-- 1 : 1 --˃     Status        ˂-- 1 : 1 --+

Read as:
...a server can have multiple instances
...an instance can have multiple databases
...a server, an instance and a database can have a status
Setup
Status Table
CREATE TABLE [Status]
(
  StatusID int,
  StatusName char(20),
  );

Status Data
INSERT INTO [Status] (StatusID, StatusName)
VALUES
(1,'Productive'),
(2,'Prod ACC'),
(3,'Prod APP'),
(4,'Test'),
(5,'Test ACC'),
(6,'Test APP'),
(7,'OFFLINE'),
(8,'Reserved'),
(9,'Decommisioned');

Server Table
CREATE TABLE [Server]
(
  ServerID int,
  ServerName char(20),
  ServerStatusID int
  );

Server Data
INSERT INTO [Server] (ServerID, ServerName, ServerStatusID)
VALUES
(1,'FirstServer',1),
(2,'SecondServer',2),
(3,'ThirdServer',5),
(4,'FourthServer',8),
(5,'FifthServer',8);

Instance Table
CREATE TABLE [Instance]
(
  InstanceID int,
  ServerID int,
  InstanceName char(30),
  InstanceStatusID int
  );

Instance Data
INSERT INTO [Instance] 
  (InstanceID, ServerID, InstanceName, InstanceStatusID)
VALUES
(1,1,'GENERAL',1),
(2,1,'TAXES',1),
(3,2,'GENERAL',9),
(4,2,'SOCIAL',2),
(5,3,'GENERAL',5),
(6,3,'FBI',8),
(7,5,'COMINGSOON',8);

Database Table
CREATE TABLE [Database]
(
  DatabaseID int,
  InstanceID int,
  DatabaseName char(30),
  DatabaseStatusID int
  );

Database Data
INSERT INTO [Database]
(DatabaseID, InstanceID, DatabaseName, DatabaseStatusID)
VALUES
(1,1,'master',1),
(2,1,'model',1),
(3,1,'msdb',1),
(4,1,'UserDB1',1),
(5,2,'master',1),
(6,2,'model',1),
(7,2,'msdb',1),
(8,2,'TaxesDB',1),
(9,4,'master',2),
(10,4,'model',2),
(11,4,'msdb',2),
(12,4,'HealthCareDB',2),
(13,5,'master',5),
(14,5,'model',5),
(15,5,'msdb',5),
(16,5,'GeneralUserDB',5),
(17,6,'master',8),
(18,6,'model',8),
(19,6,'msdb',8),
(20,6,'CriminalDB',8);

SELECT Statement without Status table involved
The initial SELECT statement involved simply joining the three tables: server, instance, database and was as follows:
-- Simple SELECT to get all information on Servers, Instances and Databases
-- The status of the server, instance or database is not returned
SELECT 
  ServerName, 
  InstanceName,
  DatabaseName 
  FROM [Server] as srv
    LEFT JOIN [Instance] as ins
      ON srv.ServerID = ins.ServerID
    LEFT JOIN [Database] as dbs
      ON ins.InstanceID = dbs.InstanceID;

Results of 1. Statement
PLEASE OBSERVE THAT...

there is a server without an instance and database
there is an instances without a database




ServerName
InstanceName
DatabaseName




FirstServer
GENERAL
master


FirstServer
GENERAL
model


FirstServer
GENERAL
msdb


FirstServer
GENERAL
UserDB1


FirstServer
TAXES
master


FirstServer
TAXES
model


FirstServer
TAXES
msdb


FirstServer
TAXES
TaxesDB


SecondServer
GENERAL
null


SecondServer
SOCIAL
master


SecondServer
SOCIAL
model


SecondServer
SOCIAL
msdb


SecondServer
SOCIAL
HealthCareDB


ThirdServer
GENERAL
master


ThirdServer
GENERAL
model


ThirdServer
GENERAL
msdb


ThirdServer
GENERAL
GeneralUserDB


ThirdServer
FBI
master


ThirdServer
FBI
model


ThirdServer
FBI
msdb


ThirdServer
FBI
CriminalDB


FourthServer
null
null


FifthServer
COMINGSOON
null



SELECT Statement involving Status table
In the next statement I decide to add the status to each element (server, instance, database) and JOINed each table with the Status table as follows:
-- Advanced SELECT to get all information on Servers, Instances and Databases 
-- including their status
SELECT 
  ServerName, 
  srvst.StatusName,
  InstanceName,
  insst.StatusName,
  DatabaseName,
  dbsst.StatusName
  FROM [Server] as srv
    JOIN [Status] as srvst
      ON srv.ServerStatusID = srvst.StatusID
    LEFT JOIN [Instance] as ins
      ON srv.ServerID = ins.ServerID
    JOIN [Status] as insst
      ON ins.InstanceStatusID = insst.StatusID
    LEFT JOIN [Database] as dbs
      ON ins.InstanceID = dbs.InstanceID
    JOIN [Status] as dbsst
      ON dbs.DatabaseStatusID = dbsst.StatusID
  ;

Results of 2. Statement
To my surprise the server without an instance and database and the server with an instance but without a database were no longer listed:



ServerName
StatusName
InstanceName
StatusName
DatabaseName
StatusName




FirstServer
Productive
GENERAL
Productive
master
Productive


FirstServer
Productive
GENERAL
Productive
model
Productive


FirstServer
Productive
GENERAL
Productive
msdb
Productive


FirstServer
Productive
GENERAL
Productive
UserDB1
Productive


FirstServer
Productive
TAXES
Productive
master
Productive


FirstServer
Productive
TAXES
Productive
model
Productive


FirstServer
Productive
TAXES
Productive
msdb
Productive


FirstServer
Productive
TAXES
Productive
TaxesDB
Productive


SecondServer
Prod ACC
SOCIAL
Prod ACC
master
Prod ACC


SecondServer
Prod ACC
SOCIAL
Prod ACC
model
Prod ACC


SecondServer
Prod ACC
SOCIAL
Prod ACC
msdb
Prod ACC


SecondServer
Prod ACC
SOCIAL
Prod ACC
HealthCareDB
Prod ACC


ThirdServer
Test ACC
GENERAL
Test ACC
master
Test ACC


ThirdServer
Test ACC
GENERAL
Test ACC
model
Test ACC


ThirdServer
Test ACC
GENERAL
Test ACC
msdb
Test ACC


ThirdServer
Test ACC
GENERAL
Test ACC
GeneralUserDB
Test ACC


ThirdServer
Test ACC
FBI
Reserved
master
Reserved


ThirdServer
Test ACC
FBI
Reserved
model
Reserved


ThirdServer
Test ACC
FBI
Reserved
msdb
Reserved


ThirdServer
Test ACC
FBI
Reserved
CriminalDB
Reserved



Findings / Solution
After checking various options with a trial and error approach I found out that the JOIN on the Status table had to be changed to a LEFT JOIN to allow for the statement to display the server without an instance or a database, and to display the instance without a database:
-- Advanced SELECT to get all information on Servers, Instances and Databases 
-- including their status
SELECT 
  ServerName, 
  srvst.StatusName,
  InstanceName,
  insst.StatusName,
  DatabaseName,
  dbsst.StatusName
  FROM [Server] as srv
    LEFT JOIN [Status] as srvst
      ON srv.ServerStatusID = srvst.StatusID
    LEFT JOIN [Instance] as ins
      ON srv.ServerID = ins.ServerID
    LEFT JOIN [Status] as insst
      ON ins.InstanceStatusID = insst.StatusID
    LEFT JOIN [Database] as dbs
      ON ins.InstanceID = dbs.InstanceID
    LEFT JOIN [Status] as dbsst
      ON dbs.DatabaseStatusID = dbsst.StatusID;

Results of 3. Statement



ServerName
StatusName
InstanceName
StatusName
DatabaseName
StatusName




FirstServer
Productive
GENERAL
Productive
master
Productive


FirstServer
Productive
GENERAL
Productive
model
Productive


FirstServer
Productive
GENERAL
Productive
msdb
Productive


FirstServer
Productive
GENERAL
Productive
UserDB1
Productive


FirstServer
Productive
TAXES
Productive
master
Productive


FirstServer
Productive
TAXES
Productive
model
Productive


FirstServer
Productive
TAXES
Productive
msdb
Productive


FirstServer
Productive
TAXES
Productive
TaxesDB
Productive


SecondServer
Prod ACC
GENERAL
Decommisioned
null
null


SecondServer
Prod ACC
SOCIAL
Prod ACC
master
Prod ACC


SecondServer
Prod ACC
SOCIAL
Prod ACC
model
Prod ACC


SecondServer
Prod ACC
SOCIAL
Prod ACC
msdb
Prod ACC


SecondServer
Prod ACC
SOCIAL
Prod ACC
HealthCareDB
Prod ACC


ThirdServer
Test ACC
GENERAL
Test ACC
master
Test ACC


ThirdServer
Test ACC
GENERAL
Test ACC
model
Test ACC


ThirdServer
Test ACC
GENERAL
Test ACC
msdb
Test ACC


ThirdServer
Test ACC
GENERAL
Test ACC
GeneralUserDB
Test ACC


ThirdServer
Test ACC
FBI
Reserved
master
Reserved


ThirdServer
Test ACC
FBI
Reserved
model
Reserved


ThirdServer
Test ACC
FBI
Reserved
msdb
Reserved


ThirdServer
Test ACC
FBI
Reserved
CriminalDB
Reserved


FourthServer
Reserved
null
null
null
null


FifthServer
Reserved
COMINGSOON
Reserved
null
null



Reference Material
Here a link to the db<>fiddle to reproduce my findings.
Question
Why does SQL Server require a LEFT JOIN on the Status table for child items that do not exist and for the query to display these items?

Is it true that using INNER JOIN after any OUTER JOIN will essentially invalidate the effects of OUTER JOIN?

You need to nest your joins. Otherwise what is happening is that it's expecting each individual join clause to return a result, but it can't if the previous one didn't return anything.
Essentially, you want the server to take the result of the inner-join of Instance and Status, and left-join all of that back to Server.
SELECT 
  ServerName, 
  srvst.StatusName,
  InstanceName,
  insst.StatusName,
  DatabaseName,
  dbsst.StatusName
FROM Server as srv
  JOIN Status as srvst
    ON srv.ServerStatusID = srvst.StatusID
  LEFT JOIN (
      Instance as ins
      JOIN Status as insst
        ON ins.InstanceStatusID = insst.StatusID
    )
    ON srv.ServerID = ins.ServerID
  LEFT JOIN (
      Database as dbs
      JOIN Status as dbsst
        ON dbs.DatabaseStatusID = dbsst.StatusID
    )
    ON ins.InstanceID = dbs.InstanceID;

In SQL Server, the parenthesis are not essential, they are purely for readability. The key is putting JOIN table2 ON ... inside another join, so it comes out to LEFT JOIN table1 JOIN table2 ON ... ON ... ie the ON clauses are nested.
This is the exact equivalent of using derived subqueries:
SELECT 
  ServerName, 
  srvst.StatusName,
  InstanceName,
  ins.StatusName,
  DatabaseName,
  dbs.StatusName
FROM Server as srv
  JOIN Status as srvst
    ON srv.ServerStatusID = srvst.StatusID
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT ins.*, insst.StatusName
      FROM Instance as ins
      JOIN Status as insst
        ON ins.InstanceStatusID = insst.StatusID
    ) ins
    ON srv.ServerID = ins.ServerID
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT dbs.*, dbsst.StatusName
      Database as dbs
      JOIN Status as dbsst
        ON dbs.DatabaseStatusID = dbsst.StatusID
    ) dbs
    ON ins.InstanceID = dbs.InstanceID;



Why does SQL Server require a LEFT JOIN on the Status table for child items that do not exist and for the query to display these items?

It doesn't, in general. It is just one of the ways to express your requirement that produces the results you are after.
Your query tries to (inner) join from a null-extended row (created by an outer join) to the Status table using a join predicate that looks for an equality match on StatusID values.
This predicate does not return true because StatusID is null on one side, there is no matching null in the Status table, and the equality predicate would reject null matches anyway. Since the join predicate fails and you have specified an inner join, no result row is produced.
For clarity, the inner join to Status could produce a result with a different join predicate.
For example, there could be a null StatusID in the Status table (something your schema allows) and the join predicate could use IS NOT DISTINCT FROM or an equivalent test where nulls match. You could also use COALESCE or ISNULL in the join predicate to select a particular status (as a default) without adding any new status rows.
There are many possibilities; the point is you could write a join predicate that would produce a match. The one you have does not.
It is possible you thought SQL Server would skip the join to Status for any rows previously null-extended by an outer join, but things don't work that way. An outer join is not an 'optional' join with subsequent short-circuiting. Perhaps some people have a mental image of them functioning that way.
Making any following joins 'outer' as a way to fix the output is close to using 'magic'—a recipe that works but isn't understood.
Why does it work here? Because, with a left outer join, the null-extended row is preserved despite there being no match in Status according to the join predicate. The missing status columns are populated with null, as usual.
An alternative solution
People do seem to find left outer joins more intuitive to work with, but there's no particular reason to prefer them otherwise. You don't have to start at the top of the hierarchy and 'join down' to rows that may or may not be present.
Let's see what happens with your schema if we instead start at the bottom of the hierarchy (the [Database] table) and work up. The first join to Status is straightforward:
SELECT
    DBS.DatabaseName,
    DBSST.StatusName
FROM dbo.[Database] AS DBS
JOIN dbo.[Status] AS DBSST
    ON DBSST.StatusID = DBS.DatabaseStatusID;

Moving up the hierarchy, we now need to add rows from the Instance table. We can't use a left outer join or inner join because there may be an instance without a database. The natural solution is to use a right join, with the associated inner join to Status:
SELECT
    INS.InstanceName,
    INSST.StatusName,
    DBS.DatabaseName,
    DBSST.StatusName
FROM dbo.[Database] AS DBS
JOIN dbo.[Status] AS DBSST
    ON DBSST.StatusID = DBS.DatabaseStatusID
RIGHT JOIN dbo.Instance AS INS
    ON INS.InstanceID = DBS.InstanceID
JOIN dbo.[Status] AS INSST
    ON INSST.StatusID = INS.InstanceStatusID;

There is no need for 'nested' joins here. We quite naturally add in any instances without a database, adding null-extended database rows as necessary. All instances are accounted for, so the inner join to Status is perfectly correct.
We follow the same approach to add in rows from the Server table, along with its status:
SELECT
    SRV.ServerName,
    SVS.StatusName,
    INS.InstanceName,
    INSST.StatusName,
    DBS.DatabaseName,
    DBSST.StatusName
FROM dbo.[Database] AS DBS
JOIN dbo.[Status] AS DBSST
    ON DBSST.StatusID = DBS.DatabaseStatusID
RIGHT JOIN dbo.Instance AS INS
    ON INS.InstanceID = DBS.InstanceID
JOIN dbo.[Status] AS INSST
    ON INSST.StatusID = INS.InstanceStatusID
RIGHT JOIN dbo.[Server] AS SRV
    ON SRV.ServerID = INS.ServerID
JOIN dbo.[Status] AS SVS
    ON SVS.StatusID = SRV.ServerStatusID;

This produces the results you want, without invoking any magic.
There are any number of ways to write a correct query specification for your requirement. I show a RIGHT JOIN alternative mostly because people seem somewhat scared by right outer joins or consider them redundant.

Because the join with status table for the child items is happening on basis of
ins.InstanceStatusID,
dbs.DatabaseStatusID which turns out to be NULL when the joins prior to it takes place in some rows.
When you do an inner join later it shows rows matched in both tables and to get the rows with null values as well you will have to use left join.
To visualize the same :
SELECT 
  ServerName, 
  srvst.StatusName,
  InstanceName,

  DatabaseName,

  ins.InstanceStatusID,
  dbs.DatabaseStatusID 
  
  FROM [Server] as srv
    LEFT JOIN [Status] as srvst
      ON srv.ServerStatusID = srvst.StatusID
    LEFT JOIN [Instance] as ins
      ON srv.ServerID = ins.ServerID
    LEFT JOIN [Database] as dbs
      ON ins.InstanceID = dbs.InstanceID 


SELECT TMP.* ,    insst.StatusName,
  dbsst.StatusName FROM (SELECT 
  ServerName, 
  srvst.StatusName,
  InstanceName,

  DatabaseName,

  ins.InstanceStatusID,
  dbs.DatabaseStatusID 
  
  FROM [Server] as srv
    LEFT JOIN [Status] as srvst
      ON srv.ServerStatusID = srvst.StatusID
    LEFT JOIN [Instance] as ins
      ON srv.ServerID = ins.ServerID
    LEFT JOIN [Database] as dbs
      ON ins.InstanceID = dbs.InstanceID ) AS TMP

    /* Here if left join is not used values which are null are skipped and only values which are in both tables are returned */

    JOIN [Status] as insst
      ON TMP.InstanceStatusID = insst.StatusID 
    JOIN [Status] as dbsst
      ON TMP.DatabaseStatusID = dbsst.StatusID ;


Which after using Left join pulls all records from left result set and the matched values from both tables joined to the resultset
SELECT TMP.* ,    insst.StatusName,
  dbsst.StatusName FROM (SELECT 
  ServerName, 
  srvst.StatusName,
  InstanceName,

  DatabaseName,

  ins.InstanceStatusID,
  dbs.DatabaseStatusID 
  
  FROM [Server] as srv
    LEFT JOIN [Status] as srvst
      ON srv.ServerStatusID = srvst.StatusID
    LEFT JOIN [Instance] as ins
      ON srv.ServerID = ins.ServerID
    LEFT JOIN [Database] as dbs
      ON ins.InstanceID = dbs.InstanceID ) AS TMP
    
    LEFT JOIN [Status] as insst
      ON TMP.InstanceStatusID = insst.StatusID 
    LEFT JOIN [Status] as dbsst
      ON TMP.DatabaseStatusID = dbsst.StatusID ;


